# Solution of Two-Level Atom Equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, atomic-physics, atomic-clocks

I am reading Foot's book. It has the following equations for a two-level atom interacting with light.

> $$\begin{align}
>   i\dot{c}_1&=c_2e^{i(\omega-\omega_0)t}\frac{\Omega}{2}, \\
>   i\dot{c}_2&=c_1e^{-i(\omega-\omega_0)t}\frac{\Omega^*}{2}.
>   \end{align} \tag{7.25}$$
> These combine to give
> $$\frac{\text{d}^2c_2}{\text{d}t^2}
>   +i(\omega-\omega_0)\frac{\text{d}c_2}{\text{d}t}
>   +\left|\frac{\Omega}{2}\right|^2c_2=0.
>   \tag{7.26}$$

This is after the rotating wave approximation. I don't know how to solve $c_1$ and $c_2$ for the general initial states when there is no detuning (i.e. $\omega=\omega_0$, which should make it easier). Can anyone give me a hint on how to solve this? This will be useful to understand how the $\pi$-pulse changes the state. I understand this is purely a math problem. But I guess atomic physicists might have a lot of experience in this and can give better insights. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Foot what? Foot who?

Comment: It is the "Atomic Physics" by Christopher J. Foot. Thanks!

Comment: Write out the two equations with no detuning and look at them. You have a second derivative and the function itself in the equation. I'm sure you have seen that one before ;)

Comment: If I assume $\Omega$ is real (as it is suggested in the book that the transition frequency between the bound states is real), then a possible solution (I just guess it instead of solving systematically) is $c_1=\cos(\frac{\theta+\Omega t}{2})$ and $c_2=-i\sin(\frac{\theta+\Omega t}{2})$. But what if $\Omega$ is not real? Thanks!